# Android: timer странно отсчитывает интервал

Tags: android, java

Есть программа, которая каждые 5 секунд издает звук.

```
myTimer = new Timer(); // Создаем таймер
    final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // Определяем задачу
        @Override
        public void run() {
            uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    soundPool.play(soundID1, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000, 5000);
```

При блокировке экрана еще 1 - 2 раза звук издается нормально, а потом интервал как-то может произвольно увеличиться, причем намного (секунд до 30). В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: При блокировке экрана ваше приложение вообще ничего делать не должно.

Comment: приложение приостанавливается. Но оно может быть перезапущено в фоне. Вот и появляются такие "странные интервалы".

Comment: Звук продолжает издавать, только со странным рандомным интервалом.
А вообще, возможно ли сделать, чтобы при блокировке программа продолжала проигрывать звук?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь Service'ом.

Comment: сделал с сервисом, результат тот же, интервал то 5 секунд, то 8, то 20